# Form action not hitting MVC controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to do a simple file upload using Html forms. I have the following in my view:

```
       <form action='@Url.Action("Save", "Order")' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="attachmentForm">
        <div >
            <label style="text-align: left;">Delivery note:</label>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; ">
            <input type="file" name="DeliveryNoteFile" id="DeliveryNote" style="width: 400px;" />
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;  margin-top:10px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:0px;">
            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                .Name("btnAddAttachment")
                .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "submit"} )
                .Content("Submit"))
        </div>            
    </form>
```

Now here is my controller method. Controller name: Order , Method name: Save.
Why is it not hitting my controller method?

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("C:\\Attachments"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

        }

        return Content("");
    }
```

Note that this is only a first draft. Any suggestions to improve this are also welcome.

Comment: just see in console html generated by ...  @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnAddAttachment").Content("Submit")

Comment: Are you sure its not hitting the method? Or do you mean `file` is null?

Comment: Not hitting the method at all

Comment: I used kendo's upload component and at least that hit the method but then the file was null

Comment: Change the method parameter to `public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase DeliveryNoteFile)` (which is the name of the control

Comment: just post html generated by @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnAddAttachment").Content("Submit")..because it should generate input type submit button then only your action will hit

Comment: Since different browsers can use different defaults for `<button>` elements, you should always explicitly set the `type` attribute - `@Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnAddAttachment").Content("Submit").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit" })`

Comment: Pass fileUploader name in action parameter i.e  public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase DeliveryNoteFile){...}

Comment: Tried changing the action to the name and id of the <input type="file">

Comment: i mean change action parameter name to filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case your **button is not of type submit** that is why it is not hitting controller action just try making submit button this way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
  .Name("btnAddAttachment")
  .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "submit"} )
  .Content("Submit"))
```

as @ AbbasGaliyakot comment worked for the user in comment section so i m also including it here.

Change controller action parameter name from `file` to `DeliveryNoteFile`.

Comment: @user3180965...try above answer it will work..if problem persists then comment...

Comment: tried changing it , no change. Still not hitting the method

Comment: html generated for the button:
<button id="btnAddAttachment" type="submit" data-role="button" class="k-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">Submit</button>

Comment: @user3180965...instead of kendo button just try simple button as <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnAddAttachment" class="k-button"/>

Comment: very strange....just try giving form action as action='/Order/Save'...@user3180965

Comment: I tried that already, I also tried using Url.Action, Url.Content

Comment: @user3180965...make sure that your submit button is inside form tag and send html generated by form tag

Comment: <form action="DeliveryNote" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="attachmentForm">
            <div>
                <label style="text-align: left;">Delivery note:</label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; ">
                <input type="file" name="DeliveryNoteFile" id="DeliveryNote" style="width: 400px;">
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;  margin-top:10px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:0px;">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnAddAttachment" class="k-button">
            </div>            
        </form>

Comment: @user3180965...form action is wrong it is 'action="DeliveryNote" ' it should be '/Order/Save'

Comment: Yes, I changed it few minutes ago and its hitting the method now! Thanks appreciate the help

Comment: @user3180965.. try taking input file as <input type="file" name="file" id="DeliveryNote" style="width: 400px;" />

Comment: change paramter name to file name  DeliveryNoteFile

Comment: I misunderstood before sorry, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this out. This would help.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "attachmentForm" }))
{
    <div >
            <label style="text-align: left;">Delivery note:</label>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; ">
            <input type="file" name="DeliveryNoteFile" id="DeliveryNote" style="width: 400px;" />
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;  margin-top:10px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:0px;">
            @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                .Name("btnAddAttachment")
                .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "submit"} )
                .Content("Submit"))
        </div> 

}
```

**And in JS you need to bind the click function of your submit button like shown below:**

```
$('#btnAddAttachment').bind('click', function () {
     $('#attachmentForm').submit();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: your answer is correct but as you can see questioner is using html form tag with url.action which will create a correct action for form tag and if we take a submit button then there is no need to submit form with jquery..

Comment: I hope you are not using MVC Areas, if so you need to specify that also like shown below:
<form action='@Url.Action("Save", "Order", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "attachmentForm", id = "attachmentForm", area = "AreaName" })' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">